# How Amy is able to bring back the people she remembers

Tags: doctor-who

In The Big Bang episode, Amy recalled the Doctor by looking at River's notebook and brought him back. Why can Amy do this?
How did River not forget the doctor? and If River didn't forget the doctor, how could she can not bring the doctor back?